# Always on top and always on all visible workspaces on reopen in Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

How to make it so that pidgin is always on top and always on all visible workspaces in Gnome, no matter if I restart it or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to use [devilspie](http://www.redips.net/linux/gnome-always-on-top/) to do this. Been a while though.

From the aboved linked page:

1) Install [Devil's Pie](http://foosel.org/linux/devilspie) (a small window-matching utility)

```
yum install devilspie
# or
yum install gdevilspie
```

2) Create gcalctool.ds file in ~/.devilspie directory and put the following lines:

```
(if
    (is (application_name) "gcalctool")
    (begin
       (above)
    )
)
```

3) Set Devil's Pie to startup on user login in session manager
open Sessions preferences and add startup program
System -> Preferences -> Personal -> Sessions [Add]

```
# fill the input fields:
Name    -> Devil's Pie
Command -> /usr/bin/devilspie
Comment -> gcalctool stays on top
```

The described procedure about making windows "always on top" is not crucial, but I hope it is helpful.